# How to display XML data into ASP.Net gridview?

Tags: asp.net, xml, gridview

Experts !
i am very new to XML. However, a webapp collects data in XML form and i have to display it (and enable edit) in an ASP.Net GridView. i need your help, please.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Answers>
  <AnswerSet>
<Answer questionId="MRN">4444</Answer>
<Answer questionId="FName">test</Answer>
<Answer questionId="LName">patient</Answer>
<Answer questionId="AddressPt">blah blah</Answer>
<Answer questionId="Governorate">xxxx</Answer>
<Answer questionId="InitialCSF">Negative</Answer>
<Answer questionId="Diagnosis"></Answer>
<Answer questionId="Description">
</Answer>
  </AnswerSet>
  <AnswerSet>
<Answer questionId="MRN">1</Answer>
<Answer questionId="FName">1</Answer>
<Answer questionId="LName">1</Answer>
<Answer questionId="AddressPt">1</Answer>
<Answer questionId="InitialCSF">Positive</Answer>
<Answer questionId="Diagnosis">dx</Answer>
<Answer questionId="Description">
</Answer>
  </AnswerSet>
 </Answers>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of to bind the XML to a gridview is to to load the xml to a DataSet and then bind the DataSet to the gridview:

```
StringReader sr= new StringReader(xml); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(sr);

Gridview.DataSource=ds.Tables[1];
Gridview.DataBind();
```

Reason for doing `ds.Tables[0]` is that your example contains 2 sets of `Answers` and when you load the DataSet with your XML, the first DataTable will contain as many rows as sets of answers you have on your XML while the second table will contain all the rows from all the set of answers.

The way LinqPad displays it is as follows:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
string xml=@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<Answers>
  <AnswerSet>
<Answer questionId=""MRN"">4444</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""FName"">test</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""LName"">patient</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""AddressPt"">blah blah</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""Governorate"">xxxx</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""InitialCSF"">Negative</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""Diagnosis""></Answer>
<Answer questionId=""Description"">
</Answer>
  </AnswerSet>
  <AnswerSet>
<Answer questionId=""MRN"">1</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""FName"">1</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""LName"">1</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""AddressPt"">1</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""InitialCSF"">Positive</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""Diagnosis"">dx</Answer>
<Answer questionId=""Description"">
</Answer>
  </AnswerSet>
 </Answers>";
StringReader sr= new StringReader(xml); 
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.ReadXml(sr);
 ds.Merge(ds,true);
 gridview.DataSoure=ds.Tables[1];
     gridview.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am happy u tried my data. i am confused though,for example i cant find "string reader". i know its my bad: please tell me in more details

Comment: StringReader is in the System.IO namespace. If you do  `using System.IO;` you should be able to create instances of this class. Our you can just fully qualify it `System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader();`

Comment: @mokokamello I have provided the code I used. Take a look at the update.

Comment: I forgot to mention i use visual web developer 2010. i want this XML for web application. thanks for your patience. i never used console.writeline before and i put your code in a "button click" sub, nothing seems to happen. i know i may be bothering you, but it is really important to understand what exactly to do. thanks again. and waiting for you update :)

Comment: @mokokamello my sample code was meant to be run from a Console application, not from a Web app. I changed the code again so that you can use it on your webapp but you need to change the `gridview` variable name for the actual name of your gridview variable.

Comment: @ Icarus : Please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058182/xml-file-to-gridview

Comment: @mokokamello the XMLDataSource looks promising for what you need. There are good examples here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13ftcwy9.aspx I honestly didn't know about it but looks like a better option. Hard to tell without actually trying it.