# Edit and Delete data from XML file using ASP.net and VB.net (or C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

In my **web application**, i have an XML file called "answers.xml"

it store the user entries in XML

```
<?xml version=""1.0""?> <Answers>  
<AnswerSet> <Answer questionId=""MRN"">4444</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""FName"">test</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""LName"">patient</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""AddressPt"">blah blah</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""Governorate"">xxxx</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""InitialCSF"">Negative</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""Diagnosis""></Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""Description""> </Answer>   
</AnswerSet>   
<AnswerSet> 
<Answer questionId=""MRN"">1</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""FName"">1</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""LName"">1</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""AddressPt"">1</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""InitialCSF"">Positive</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""Diagnosis"">dx</Answer> 
<Answer questionId=""Description""> </Answer>   
</AnswerSet>  </Answers>
```

i can add data to the XML file using a DLL file i downloaded from the internet.
**i need a way to change the data (edit / delete) in the xml file using ASP.net / VB.net or C#**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), because simply you can search it and change the elements or attributes:

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse("<AnswerSet> <Answer questionId=\"10\" FName=\"test\"> </Answer></AnswerSet> ");
// or if you have related file simply use XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(fileFullName);
var element =
      doc1.Descendants("AnswerSet").Elements("Answer")
      .Where(x => x.Attribute("FName") != null 
            && x.Attribute("FName").Value == "test").SingleOrDefault();
if (element != null)
{
   var attr = element.Attribute("FName");
   attr.Value = "Changed";
}

doc1.Save(filePath);
```

**Edit:** `Descendants("AnswerSet")` finds AnswerSet elements, Elements("Answer") finds Answer Elements,

```
Where(x => x.Attribute("FName") != null 
            && x.Attribute("FName").Value == "test").SingleOrDefault();
```

finds element which contains attribute `FName` and attribute value equals to `test`, `SingleOrDefault` in the last, says you should have just one such an element, Also you can change it (just call `ToList()`) to find all related elements, and finally in `if` I'll change the value of element, Also at the end we save it again with changed values.

This language (linq2xml) is too easy and functions like `Descendant` and `Elements` are most use full functions in it, so there is no need to have special knowledge you can simply come up to many problems by knowing this functions.

Comment: I didn't mention [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx) cause it's very simple and as you can see it's documented by MSDN.

Comment: thanks @Saeed Amiri vote up. but u suggested a solution that works with fixed field names. normal user cant do anything if he needs to add a new field, right? i was thinking of a solution that load all fields into a gridview, then edit and update. whenever we add a new field, it populates in the gridview without code modification.

Comment: @mokokamello editing element in XML is different thing than editing grideview, in fact you can load your xml in gridview, by simply getting Filed values into list, but this code is different from updating or editing, because your classes should be separated from each other as many as possible, specially your way of saving or business should be hide from UI implementation, If next day you want move it to silver light, again you should code, this known as Separation Of Concern rule. Also this can be dynamic and affect on many fields, but I prevent from wrote it cause of confusion.

Comment: thanks @Saeed Amiri, i understand from u it is very difficult to edit in XML file, or is it doable. please help me :)

Comment: @mokokamello it's not difficult  first read something about linq (for e.g google 101 linq sample, and test them) then you simply can handle all of your requirements, and then if you have a problem, we are here to help you, I wrote this answer to introduce you, `DOM` and `SAX` are other options for working with xml but they are old and is better to use `XDocument`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the XmlDocument class that comes with .Net. No need to download something.
Or do I miss something?

First thing I found, it's for VB, but the concept stays the same for c#.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317662

You can just load any xml file and then use XPath to access any node and change it.

Comment: i never used xml for datastorage before, so please be patient with me and tell me more details

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [XmlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494y92bs.aspx) Control.